# Find no of select query executed per hour in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to find the number of select query executed per hour in mysql ?

Is there ant way to find this ?

Please help me out.

Thanks,

Nitesh Kumar

Comment: And about the question: you might find http://www.electrictoolbox.com/logging-queries-with-mysql/ useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could enable MySQL's [general query logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-log.html) to a table (note that this has a non-negligible performance impact) and then perform queries on the data:

```
SELECT   DATE(event_time), HOUR(event_time), COUNT(*) AS select_queries
FROM     mysql.general_log
WHERE    argument LIKE 'select %'
GROUP BY DATE(event_time), HOUR(event_time)
```